# How to send existing data to firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Flutter I used raisedbutton to send data to firestore,
how can I put the condition before sending data (when the user pushes `raisedbutton` the app is not sending data to my firestore database if some fields are empty or the device is not connected to internet)?

My code:

1. function to check internet:

```
 Future<bool> check() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          internetdisponible = 'vous avez ajouté un nouveau medcin \n MERCI';
        });
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        internetdisponible = 'Vérifier Votre connexion internet Svp';
      });
    }
  }
....
```

2. raisedbutton code (coolect data from textfields and DropdownMenuItem):

```
RaisedButton(
    color: Color(0xff11b719),
    textColor: Colors.white,
    child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Envoyer ",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
          ],
        )),
    onPressed: () async {
      check();
      if (medicalType == null ||
          validatetextfield(nomdata.text) == false ||
          validatetextfield(mobiledata.text) == false ||
          validatetextfield(addressedata.text) == false) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("SVP Remplir tout les champs")));
      } else {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = {
          "specialité": medicalType,
          "Nom:": nomdata.text,
          "Téléphone:": mobiledata.text,
          "adresse:": addressedata.text,
          "autre:": autredata.text,
        };
        {
          var myStoredData = await readData();
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection(myStoredData)
              .add(data);
          return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('$internetdisponible',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('OK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }
  
      }
    },
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a boolean from the `check()` function :

```dart
  Future<bool> check() async {
    var isConnected = false;
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          internetdisponible = 'vous avez ajouté un nouveau medcin \n MERCI';
        });
        isConnected = true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        internetdisponible = 'Vérifier Votre connexion internet Svp';
      });
    }
    return isConnected;
  }
```

And test the return value of the `check()` function in the `onPressed` callback before sending the data:

```dart
  onPressed: () async {
      if (medicalType == null ||
          validatetextfield(nomdata.text) == false ||
          validatetextfield(mobiledata.text) == false ||
          validatetextfield(addressedata.text) == false) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text("SVP Remplir tout les champs")));
      } else {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = {
          "specialité": medicalType,
          "Nom:": nomdata.text,
          "Téléphone:": mobiledata.text,
          "adresse:": addressedata.text,
          "autre:": autredata.text,
        };
        {
          
          if ((await check())) {
            var myStoredData = await readData();
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection(myStoredData)
              .add(data);
          }
          
          return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('$internetdisponible',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('OK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }
  
      }
    },
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: i have this error : A negation operand must have a static type of 'bool'. (non_bool_negation_expression at [myproject] lib\screens\Adding.dart:274)                                    in if (!check()) .

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that `check()` return a `Future`. You have to use `await check()` to get the value of the `Future`, I have updated the code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you the code is worked, but in mode offline still send data to firestore when the device connect to internet,
ithink the condition if (!(await check())) should be before async {...} (the user c'ant send any data if no internet ) but i dont know how to do this?

Comment: Just remove the `!` before the `await check()`. I have updated the code. it should work.

Comment: thank you very much , finally it worked,if possible, i have a last question  about connectivity can i change the function to detect if the device is connected without ping google.com?

Comment: Yes, you can check if the wifi or the mobile data is enabled on the device, but the wifi or the mobile data may be enabled without internet access. To check if the device has access to the Internet you have to ping a remote server. If my answer solved the problem, can you accept and upvote my answer?

Comment: thank you very much ,ok i will vote for it